# Serializing json in retrofit 2 errors

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, retrofit2

I am following some kotlin path on Google and for the bookshelf app I want to parse and serialize the response to this GET request:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=jazz+history

I am using retrofit2 with this converter (from Mars application)

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
```

and to build the retrofit object I am doing this:

```
    private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build()
```

This is my serializable:

```
@Serializable
data class QueryResponse(
    val kind: String,
    val totalItems: Int,
    val items: List<Book>?,
)
```

and here the method from my interface:

```
    @GET("volumes")
    suspend fun getBooks(@Query("q") query: String): List<QueryResponse>
```

when parsing the response, I get the error:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead at path:
```

Looks like I am not parsing correctly the json (according to other answers, maybe I am parsing the reponse.content instead of response.body). Questions here:

1. how to debug such issue?
2. how can I ensure to parse the body and not the whole response content?
3. (Optional):
   I saw a different implementation of the app where the coder expects a Response<> instead of a List<>, using gson as serializer, and then proceeds to retrieve the body if the response was successful:

```
    @GET("volumes")
    suspend fun getBooks(@Query("q") query: String): Response<QueryResponse>

[...]

     override suspend fun getBooks(query: String): List<Book>? {
        return try {
            val res = bookshelfApiService.getBooks(query)
            if (res.isSuccessful) {
                res.body()?.items ?: emptyList()
                [...]
```

And this seems to work. Why the former does crash and the latter not?